# PowerShell Copy-Item what is the mask for Included folders?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have folders like this:

```
a
    |
    - c 
        |
        - abc.txt
        
b
```

I want to copy every included file with some exclusions and folders

`Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose "a\*" -Destination "b" -Include "*.*" -Exclude "Web.config" -Container`

but when I use those masks, then folders are not being copied

when I remove `-Include "*.*"`

`Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose "a\*" -Destination "b" -Exclude "Web.config" -Container`

then everything works fine, here's the log:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\Users\\Documents\test\a\c Destination:
C:\Users\\Documents\test\b\c".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\\Documents\test\b\c".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\\Documents\test\a\c\dsd.txt
Destination: C:\Users\\Documents\test\b\c\dsd.txt".
```

So basically my question is, what's the mask for folders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb

Masks for folders will be just: `*`

Thus,
`*.*` => `*`